# Rolling min without replacement

Tags: r

Given a vector (`vec`) and a window size of 5,

```
winsz <- 5L
vec <- c(9, 3, 10, 5, 6, 2, 4, 8, 7, 1)
```

Is there a faster way to calculate rolling minimum without replacement?

---

Rolling min w/o replacement: Using `vec` as an example and window size of 5.

In the first pass, the min is extracted from first 5 elements (9, 3, 10, 5, 6). Min is 3 in the first pass.

In the 2nd pass, the min is extracted from 4 elements left over from the first pass (9, 10, 5, 6) and the new windowed element (2). Min is 2 in the second pass.

In the 3rd pass, the min is extracted from elements left over from the previous pass (9, 10, 5, 6) and the new windowed element (4). Min is 4 in the third pass. So on and so forth.

The result from the example is

```
 [1]  3  2  4  5  6  1  7  8  9 10
```

Please kindly exclude `Rcpp` implementation for now.

---

Current implementation and timing code:

```
#rolling min without replacement
set.seed(0L)
N <- 10e5
winsz <- 5L
vec <- sample(N)

mtd0 <- compiler::cmpfun(function(x) {
    subx <- x[seq_len(winsz)]
    n <- 1L
    drawn <- rep(NA_integer_, length(x))
    while (n <= length(x)-winsz) {
        idx <- which.min(subx)
        drawn[n] <- subx[idx]            
        subx[idx] <- x[n+winsz]
        n <- n + 1
    }
    drawn[tail(seq_along(drawn), winsz)] <- sort(subx)
    drawn
})

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mtd0(vec), times=3L)
```

Around 8s for a window size of 5 and vector of length 1e6.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how this is going to clock in but here is another option

```
f <- function(x, window = 5) {
    ret <- numeric(length = length(x))
    i <- 1L
    while (length(x) > 0) {
        idx.min <- which.min(x[1:window])
        ret[i] <- x[idx.min]
        x <- x[-idx.min]
        i <- i + 1
    }
    return(ret)
}
f(vec)
# [1]  3  2  4  5  6  1  7  8  9 10
```

---

Or

```
f2 <- function(x, window = 5) {
    ret <- numeric(length = length(x))
    i <- 1L
    while (i <= length(x)) {
        idx.min <- which.min(x[1:(window + i - 1)])
        ret[i] <- x[idx.min]
        x[idx.min] <- NA
        i <- i + 1
    }
    return(ret)
}
```

---

**On a side note...**

Kudos for the `numeric(length = length(x))` part goes to @RonakShah; it's interesting that `numeric(length = length(x))` is much faster than `rep(0, length(x))` (which is what I wrote originally;-)

```
res <- microbenchmark(
    rep = rep(0, 10^6),
    numeric = numeric(length = 10^6)
)
#Unit: microseconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#     rep 1392.582 2549.219 3682.897 2694.137 3098.073 14726.81   100   a
# numeric  424.257 1592.110 2902.232 1727.431 2174.159 11747.87   100   a
```

Comment: Ah but there is much more room for improvement;-) for example it turns out that your `numeric(length = length(vec))` is much faster than `rep(0, length(vec))` (`microbenchmark` says by more than a factor of 3). I got making `i` an integer rather than numeric from you too, which should be faster. I'm curious to see what other solutions will come up. Should be fun:-)

Comment: Ok so I ran a `microbenchmark` analysis, and this is significantly worse than chinsoon12's implementation:-( This has me stumped as I don't really understand why...

Comment: I think `x <- x[-idx.min]` copies a long vector too many times

Comment: @chinsoon12 Perhaps. I've added another version without the copying step where we set min elements to `NA` but a quick & superficial benchmark check shows that this hardly makes a difference. Still too slow...

Answer (score 0):

Timings so far:

```
#rolling min without replacement
set.seed(0L)
N <- 10e4
winsz <- 5L
vec <- sample(N)

f <- compiler::cmpfun(function(x, window = 5) {
    ret <- numeric(length = length(x))
    i <- 1L
    while (length(x) > 0) {
        idx.min <- which.min(x[1:window])
        ret[i] <- x[idx.min]
        x <- x[-idx.min]
        i <- i + 1
    }
    return(ret)
})

mtd0 <- compiler::cmpfun(function(x) {
    subx <- x[seq_len(winsz)]
    n <- 1L
    drawn <- rep(NA_integer_, length(x))
    while (n <= length(x)-winsz) {
        idx <- which.min(subx)
        drawn[n] <- subx[idx]    
        subx[idx] <- x[n+winsz]
        n <- n + 1
    }
    drawn[tail(seq_along(drawn), winsz)] <- sort(subx)
    drawn
})

mtd1 <- compiler::cmpfun(function(x) {
    res <- Reduce(function(ans, s) {
            v <- ans$students
            idx <- which.min(v)
            list(students=c(v[-idx], s), drawn=v[idx])
        },
        x=as.list(x[seq_along(x)[-seq_len(winsz)]]),
        init=list(students=x[seq_len(winsz)], drawn=NULL),
        accumulate=TRUE)
    c(unlist(lapply(res, `[[`, "drawn")), sort(res[[length(res)]]$students))
})

#all.equal(f(vec), mtd0(vec))
# [1] TRUE

#all.equal(mtd0(vec), mtd1(vec))
# [1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f(vec), mtd0(vec), mtd1(vec), times=3L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr         min          lq        mean      median        uq        max neval cld
    f(vec) 16234.97047 16272.00705 16457.05138 16309.04363 16568.092 16827.1400     3   b
 mtd0(vec)    75.18676    83.34443    96.03222    91.50209   106.455   121.4078     3  a 
 mtd1(vec)   301.56747   342.36437   427.33052   383.16127   490.212   597.2628     3  a
```